# What expressions/functions are supported in numeric fields?

Tags: unity

In the Unity Editor, we can type an expression in a numeric field and press Enter to apply the result of the expression. For example, for a float field, we can type `10 * 5`:

[image: Expression 10 * 5 typed into float field]

If we press enter, the expression is resolved to `50` and that value is applied to the field.

[image: Resolved to 50]

Addition, subtraction, and division are also supported.

We can also type some mathematical functions, e.g.:

```
floor(131.8)
ceil(22.2)
round(5.5)
```

What other expression syntax/functions are supported?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [documentation for editing properties](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EditingValueProperties.html), the C#  [ExpressionEvaluator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExpressionEvaluator.html) is used for processing numeric field expressions. The expressions that can be evaluated are:

- arithmetic operators `a+b`, `a-b`, `a*b`, `a/b`,
- power (`a^b`) and modulo (`a%b`) operators,
- parentheses,
- math functions `sqrt(a)`, `floor(a)`, `ceil(a)`, `round(a)`,
- trigonometric functions `cos(a)`, `sin(a)`, `tan(a)` (argument expressed in radians), and a constant `pi`.

Supported number types are: `int`, `float`, `long`, `double`.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't found that documentation when I was searching.

Comment: You're very welcome! I put the links in mostly for future reference - Unity is generally pretty good about adding versioned docs as the editor evolves & it's possible that in the future the supported options may change. I also thought it's possible that someone might want to use `ExpressionEvaluator` directly themselves for a plug-in, command line game or something & that seemed like another good reason to link it in. Glad it helped & happy deving!